# Binary Search Tree Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

```
Search(T,k)
x<- root[T]
while x != NULL and k != key[x] 
do 
  if k<key[x]
    then x <- left[x]
  else x <- right[x]
    return x
```

I just started with algorithms and I often see "<-" this and key[x] terminology can someone tell me what is key is it an array ? x was getting the root value and then it is used as an index ? I fail to understand this. Please explain.

Comment: The notation here is a bit different. `x` in `key[x]` is not an index. It actually means "the value of key at node `x`". Similarly with `left[x]` and right[x]`, they mean "the left and right nodes of `x`. `<-` is simply an assignment statement.

Comment: If you're more familiar with object-oriented notation, you can read `key[x]` as `x.key`, `left[x]` as `x.left` and so on.

Comment: @hammar, dont'you mean C-style notation under object-oriented notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pseudocode (not a real language).

In this case `<-` means 'is assigned' and can be thought of as doing what `=` does in modern languages. `key[x]` is shorthand for the `key` property of structure/object `x` (this doesn't mean it's a member of the `x` class necessarily, it could be retrieved from a data structure such as a map. The actual implementation is left up to the algorithm implementer.

So the above algorithm could be written in C as:

```
Node* Search(Tree* T, Key k)
{
    Node* x = T->Root();
    while ((x != NULL) && (k != x->Key())
    {
        if (k < x->Key())
            x = x->Left();
        else
            x = x->Right();
    }

    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like psuedo-code.  Think of the `<-` as the assignment operator `=` in Java.  You also sometimes see is as `:=` in other psuedo-code variations.

`x` is used as a pointer to a node in the tree.  The `key` is the value you usually find in a circle when the tree is drawn out, and `left` and `right` is the node's two children.

Edit: That psuedo-code is a little off as well.  James' example is good.